# Is it possible for a campaign-specific magic item to be used outside of the campaign it is from?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, campaign

I am currently planning to run a game for my family.

Is it possible for campaign-specific magic items to be used (not just carried) outside of the campaign they are from? For example, could *Saint Markovia's thighbone* from *Curse of Strahd* be used in a Waterdeep adventure?

Comment: In Adventurer's League play, or just like at your home table?

Comment: Either method of play.

Comment: Which is the actual situation you have?

Comment: and are you GM or a player?

Comment: I am currently a player but I am planning on being a GM soon for my family. I am asking for any situation. Would it be up to what the story I make up is?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. As the question stands, the site needs more information. To give one example, the question may be asking *Is it possible for one particular DM to allow a magic item into his campaign that was acquired by a character during a published campaign originally run by a different DM?* However, that's just one way the question can be read—there are many others. Please detail your *specific* situation, and I'm sure someone will offer some help. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: My question is for general knowledge and not for a specific campaign or situation.

Comment: That's fine, too, but I think the site still needs to understand better the situation as you imagine it. Are the campaigns being run by the same or different DMs? Is the campaign part of organized play like Adventurer's League? Is the question making a distinction between *campaigns* and *settings*? By *use*, does that mean *function* or just *carry around until the campaign of origin is returned to*? That kind of thing. A more expansive example of what you have in mind, I think, could be helpful.

Comment: In general, you'll get better answers here if you ask about a specific situation rather than for "general knowledge". We're best at solving specific problems you actually encounter, and our ability to help breaks down if you ask about broad hypotheticals. Ask about your specific situation, and if the answers don't give you enough info to generalize your knowledge to other situations, then feel free to ask another question about it!

Comment: While a narrower question would get 'better' answers, based on certain definitions of 'better', I think the question is perfectly answerable now, especially given the advice in the DMG about making worlds your own.

Comment: I believe you are over complicating this. It is a simple question but for sake of argument let's say same DM, one setting to another (like the example in the question), and use means use. Use only means using as in a functional tool or weapon.

Comment: Not adventurer's league either. Use does not mean carrying for the time being.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing to say you can't - there is nothing specific about [*Saint Markovia's thighbone*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/saint-markovias-thighbone) that makes it applicable to the CoS adventure explicitly, other than the lore. Otherwise, it works the same way as a *mace of disruption* (*Curse of Strahd*, p. 222; emphasis mine):

> #### Saint Markovia's Thighbone
>
> *Weapon (mace), rare (requires attunement)*
>
> **Saint Markovia's thighbone has the properties of a *mace of disruption*.** If it scores one or more hits against a vampire or a vampire spawn in the course of a single battle, the thighbone crumbles into dust once the battle concludes.